# Getting values from multiple HTML sliders

Tags: javascript, html, url, sliders

I'm looking for a way to grab the values of 2 HTML sliders and append them to a url (which would then be used to change an image source).

This is what I'm currently working with:

```js
    var localhost = "http://localhost:8080";
    var chemin = "/cam_pre/";
    var zoom_val = document.getElementById("zoom_val").value;
    document.getElementById("zoom_val").innerHTML=zoom_val;
    var rot_val = document.getElementById("rot_val").value;
    document.getElementById("rot_val").innerHTML=rot_val;
    document.getElementById("img").src =localhost+chemin+"camera_"+zoom_val+"_"+rot_val+ ".png";
    function showzoom(newVal){
          document.getElementById("zoom_val").innerHTML=newVal;
          document.getElementById("img").src = document.getElementById("img").src = localhost+chemin+"camera_"+newVal+"_"+rot_val+ ".png";
        }
    function showrot(newVal){
          document.getElementById("rot_val").innerHTML=newVal;
          document.getElementById("img").src = localhost+chemin+"camera_"+zoom_val+"_"+newVal+ ".png";
        }
```

```html
<figure>
        <img id="img" alt="" src="http://localhost:8080/service/camera_init.png">
      </figure>
    <form action="/service" method="GET">
      <fieldset>
         <legend>Gérez les paraméttres de la caméra:</legend>
           <label for="zoom_val">Zoom:</label>
            Loin <input type="range" name="zoom_val" id="zoom_val" min="0.5" max="2" step="0.5" oninput="showzoom(this.value)" onchange="showzoom(this.value)"> Proche<br>
           <label for="rot_val">Rotation:</label>
            0 <input type="range" name="rot_val" id="rot_val" min="0" max="1.5" step="0.5" oninput="showrot(this.value)" onchange="showrot(this.value)"> Pi/2<br>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I'm completely new to HTML and Javascript so please be patient =).

Comment: _"I'll refrain from posting the methods I've already used, since none have worked"_ Please don't refrain as it a) seems like you didn't try anything and you're looking for us to do all the work and b) saves us from possibly duplicating anything you've already attempted.

Comment: Welcome to SO, the point is to post the code that hasn't worked so that we can tell you how to fix it

Comment: My code is absolutely disgusting but here you go (Added to the OP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<script>` tag should be at the end of your HTML file. Since your javascript is not wrapped in a function its going to immediately get the values from your sliders and update the image source. (This could be what you want im not sure)

Then when each slider changes you call a function which updates the link. I dont think you need the `oninput="showzoom(this.value)"` but you definitely need the onchange() event.

Also in the `showZoom()` function you have this line

```
document.getElementById("img").src = document.getElementById("img").src = localhost+chemin+"camera_"+newVal+"_"+rot_val+ ".png";;
```

which should be

```
document.getElementById("img").src = localhost + chemin + "camera_" + newVal + "_" + rot_val + ".png";
```

This final JS script is working fine for me:

```
<script>
    var localhost = "http://localhost:8080";
    var chemin = "/cam_pre/";
    var zoom_val = document.getElementById("zoom_val").value;
    var rot_val = document.getElementById("rot_val").value;

    document.getElementById("img").src =localhost+chemin+"camera_"+zoom_val+"_"+rot_val+ ".png";

    console.log(zoom_val, rot_val);

    function showzoom(newVal) {
          document.getElementById("zoom_val").innerHTML = newVal;
          document.getElementById("img").src = localhost + chemin + "camera_" + newVal + "_" + rot_val + ".png";

          console.log(document.getElementById("img").src);
    }

    function showrot(newVal) {
          document.getElementById("rot_val").innerHTML=newVal;
          document.getElementById("img").src = localhost + chemin + "camera_" + zoom_val + "_" + newVal + ".png";
          console.log(document.getElementById("img").src);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the time you took to answer,
However, while the code does actually run fine, the image I'm trying to display at the beginning ("camera_init.png") does not show up, and neither does the changed image when I slide the sliders. What could be causing this?

Thanks again =)

Comment: Solved it, it was a problem with my server's setup. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript to get value of an input by ID**

```
document.getElementById('ID').value;
```

**JavaScript to append an input value with a given ID to a string**

```
myVar = "string" + document.getElementById('ID').value;
```

**JavaScript to change image element source attribute given an ID**

```
document.getElementById("imageID").src="/newImageSource.png";
```